# phpcs version not specified

Tags: php, phpcs

I spent hours on Google searching for an answer too this before asking, in phpcs I had this error "PHP version not specified", but I couldn't find an answer on Google, eventually I've just came across this "PHP Version 5" which cleared the error up, but I'm baffled as PHP 5 is out of date, I'm on PHP 7.2.10.

If anyone could shed light on this I'd much appreciate it, many thanks.

Edit: I've just added the @ lines at the top, and it breaks the "PHP Version 5" as it's saying "PHP version not specified".

- @category
- @package
- @author
- @license
- @link
- PHP version 5

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/php-version-not-specified-warning-codesniffer

Comment: thanks, but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: you check also with `*PHP Version 5` with uppercase in `v`?

Comment: I have yeah, both upper and lowercase

Comment: To let the sniffs know what version of PHP you are targeting, the php_version configuration option can be used.
`$ phpcs --config-set php_version 50403`
check on: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Configuration-Options#setting-the-php-version

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

"php version" All letters will be in lower case

*** php version 7.2.10**

*** Must be placed before @tags**

Comment: Apparently, the letters don't have to be all lower case, so 'PHP version 8.1.1' works